# AWTUtilities setWindowOpaque causing problems

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, awtutilities

I have a modal `JDialog` that I set non-opaque with a call to the [`com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) method, `setWindowOpaque(this, false)`.

I encounter problems when I set the modal `JDialog` to be non-opaque. For example, when I click on a button a non-opaque dialog, it pop up correctly but after a couple of opening and closing of the dialog, it does open. It is not visible; and, since it is modal, we can't click on the button contained in the parent panel. It's like it is frozen, but that's only because of the modal dialog.

If I remove the call to the method `setWindowOpaque(this, false)`, it works without any problem.

Does anyone know what is going on?

I am using Java version "1.6.0_26" on Windows XP.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: *AWTUtilities.. java version "1.6.0_26"*  There is no AWTUtilities in the Java 6 J2SE.  Are you referring to a `sun` or `com.sun` class, Java 7, or something else?

Comment: See also [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, yeah I'm obviously refering to com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities class.

Comment: I resolved the problem by creating a small example. Found that the problem is not related to the setWindowOpaque method. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, had a similar problem, sometimes the window was not responding, or transparency was broken... weird problems.

The solution, at least for me, was calling `new TransparentWindow()` inside `invokeLater`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TransparentWindow w = new TransparentWindow();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

TransparentWindow is a class extending JWindow that uses `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(window,false);` to create a transparent window with rounded transparent corners as explained here: [Soft clipping and per-pixel translucency for Swing windows](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/03/03/soft-clipping-and-per-pixel-translucency-for-swing-windows.html)